# How to add referral exclusions in Google Analytics 4 (GA4) properties

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

We have a website which uses a Stripe hosted payment page, so the user is taken to stripe.com for payment and then redirected to our website. In Universal Analytics we can add 'Referral exclusions' to ignore this in the report so that our referral data is correct. I.e. it doesn't start a new session every time someone makes a payment.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en

In our new GA4 property this isn't possible (it's not a feature of GA4). And all of our payments from Stripe have an 'ourwebsite.com' referral. All the payments in PayPal which stays onsite have the correct referral Email, Ads etc.

After looking at some solutions I have tried to add the following (independently) to the payment success page (after Stripe). But neither is working.

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('set', {'page_referrer': null});
```

AND

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('set', {'page_referrer': 'https://ourwesbite.com/payment/gateway'});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Google has rolled out the feature to support this functionality now.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10327750?ck_subscriber_id=750579406

You can either configure unwanted referrals in the GA admin.

Or you can set ignore_referrer=true for individual events as per this article.

```
gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXX', {
  ignore_referrer: 'true'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Would adding the stripe domain to the "Configure Your Domains" setting under the Data Streams resolve this?

Go to Admin > Data Streams > Select your data stream > More tagging settings > Configure your domains

Comment: Thanks for responding to this issue. I am trying this and will update here if it works (good idea). I have a feeling that the same GA code will need to be present on all sites for the correct tracking to flow through the domains. But let's hope I'm wrong.